# How to use nested getline() function to get ride of special characters and punctuation in a string?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, getline, punctuation

I am using getline() function to get ride of special characters and punctuation in a sentence, so that when i display the words contained in the sentence, it does not have any other character beside a-z (or A-Z). The problem is that it gets long, and I don't think it is really efficient. I would like to know if I can do it in a efficient way. I am using Dev-C++, the code below is in C++. Thanks for your help.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
 int i=0;
 char y; 
 string prose, word, word1, word2;
 cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
 getline(cin, prose);

 string mot;
 stringstream ss(prose);


 y=prose[i++];
 if (y=' ')   // if character space is encoutered...


  cout<<endl << "list of words in the prose " << endl;
  cout << "---------------------------"<<endl;
  while(getline(ss, word, y))  //remove the space...
   {

      stringstream ss1(word);      

     while(getline(ss1, word1, ','))  //remove the comma...
       {

          stringstream ss2(word1);  //remove the period
          while(getline(ss2, word2, '.'))
           cout<< word2 <<endl; //and display just the word without space, comma or period.
       }
   }      


     cout<<'\n';
    system ("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

#############################output

Enter a sentence: What? When i say: "Nicole, bring me my slippers, and give me m
y night-cap," is that prose?

### list of words in the prose

What?
When
i
say:
"Nicole
bring
me
my
slippers
and
give
me
my
night-cap
"
is
that
prose?

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: "The problem is that it gets long, and I don't think it is really efficient." Do I understand correctly that you are only asking how to improve performance? Why even care unless it's really running slow? Have you measured the performance?

Comment: not in terms of performance, but in term of extra (and maybe unnecessary) lines of code.

Comment: btw., I have a remark about your `if (y=' ')` statement. The only thing that does is that the next line, `cout<<endl << "list of ... ` is **only executed** if the first character of the entered string is a space - I don't think that's what you intented to do, right?

Comment: yeah, I will move it up before the statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
std::string s(":;[{abcd 8239234");

s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(),
                       s.end(),
                       [](const char c) { return !isalpha(c); }),
        s.end());
```

If you do not have a C++11 compiler, define a predicate instead of using a lambda (online demo http://ideone.com/NvhKq).

Comment: you might note that this is C++11 code. I think not everyone already uses a compliant compiler ;)

Comment: oh and your current code would also remove the dash (-) and the quotes (") - that doesn't seem to be what OP wanted!

Comment: @nyarlathotep, just define a predicate instead of the lambda.

Comment: @nyarlathotep, the code is an example of how to do it. The OP can easily change this to his exact needs. But: _it does not have any other character beside a-z (or A-Z)._ which seems the `-` and `"` is not required.

Comment: right, the example and the description seem to contradict each other at the moment (or the code just isn't complete yet)

Comment: My compiler displays  the following error: "confused by earlier errors, bailing out." when trying to use remove_if().

Comment: @T4000, did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: @T4000, if your compiler is not C++11 compliant then you cannot use the lambda (the code in the answer). You will have to define a predicate, see the link in the answer for an example.

Comment: I defined the predicate, tested the code, and now, it works fine. Thanks hmjd!